# Change color using CSS Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, branding

I am using one of the default templates for SharePoint branding. How do I easily tweak the color as shown below in SharePoint Online? I Googled with no help.

So far I changed the background using a WYSIWYG upload feature. The default WYSIWIG editor does not let me change the white background to SOLID white rather than transparent. As you can see I used inspect element to showcase the change I want to make using CSS. I dont know how to implement it because its SharePoint Online.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You would want to create an alternate css file. In it you would do

```
.ms-pub-contentLayout {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Save this css file in your site, then apply it using the Alternate CSS URL option in the MasterPage options, accessible via Site Settings, Master page, Alternate CSS section aka `/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx`.

Comment: Eric, where would the "/_layouts/15/" directory be located?This is SharePoint Online 2013 and since I am new to it I do not know where those core files are located.

Comment: Site Settings -> Master page, Alternate CSS section